# AndroMDA is not generating code

Tags: andromda

I have recently started with AndroMDA and was trying to write a application. I am doing following:

- created project using AndroMDA archetype
- created two entity classes
- created two value object classes for above two entities
- created a service class

Now when I run `mvn install` maven couldn't find my entity classes, nor my value object classes.

I had just generated these files (with `mvn install` I did before giving a reference of entities to service class).

My question is why is AndroMDA not creating these classes before using them?